# Ejabberd doesn't creates ejabberd.yml file in Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, ejabberd

I have installed **Ejabberd** from the [process-one website](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads) on Windows Server 2016.

The installation worked properly, but the installation doesn't create a `ejabber.yml` file. When I look for an example I add to the path where it was needed, it doesn't work. I can connect with the service through a web page, but the login doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that I was trying to install Ejabberd from a user account, and not from the administrator one.